# How to place a DIV under (and not behind) a DIV with fixed position?

Tags: html, css

how can I get the green DIV top to start at the bottom of the red DIV (which has a fixed height? (I know that I could play with margin top but in my case that would not work as the red header DIV will have a variable height i.e. when users scroll down by 10px, header height will change from 120px to 80px - note that for some reason that JS part does not work on jsfiddle) http://jsfiddle.net/NHE2d/ Thanks

[image]

```
<div class="header">
<div class="logo">Logo</div>                            
<ul class="drop_menu">
<li><a href='#'>Link 1</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href='#'>Sub Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Sub Link 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href='#'>Link 2</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href='#'>Sub Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Sub Link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Sub Link 3</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Sub Link 4</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href='#'>Link 3</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href='#'>Sub Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Sub Link 3</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Sub Link 4</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
        </div>
        <!-- end header-->

            <!-- template -->
<div class="block"></div>


.block {

    width:90%;
    height: 800px;
    background: green;
}

.header {
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
    color: #124191;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 28px;
    display: table;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 999999;
        opacity: 0.7;
}

.logo {
vertical-align: middle;
line-height: 120px; /* this is set to same height as the div */
left:0;

color: #333;
font-size: 30px;
font-weight: 800;
letter-spacing: -1px;
margin-left: 60px;
}

 .drop_menu {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    list-style-type:none;
line-height: 120px
    right: 0;
    display: table;
    z-index: 3000;
       display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    right: 0;

}

.bigheight {
    background:red;

}
.shortheight {
    background:green;
    height: 60px;
       -webkit-transition-duration: 400ms;
        -webkit-transition-function: linear;

}
.drop_menu li { display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle; float: right;}

.drop_menu li a {
    padding:9px 20px;
    display:block;
    color:#666;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-transform: uppercase;



}

/* Submenu */
.drop_menu ul {
    position:absolute;
    left:-9999px;
    top:-9999px;
    list-style-type:none;
}
.drop_menu li:hover { position:relative; background:#5FD367; }
.drop_menu li:hover ul {
    left:0px;
    top:30px;
    background:#5FD367;
    padding:0px;
}

.drop_menu li:hover ul li a {
    padding:5px;
    display:block;
    width:168px;
    text-indent:15px;
    background-color:#5FD367;
}
.drop_menu li:hover ul li a:hover { background:#005555; }
```

Comment: you will need javascript to find out height of your red div(scrollHeight) , then use this height as a padding-top on body or whatever else way you want to set this margin.

Comment: here is what i meant : http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/iLjrI

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/P9Pef/

Comment: @Ron You have a hash in front of `position:fixed`, breaking it.  When you actually make this fixed, it doesn't work per the OP's question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will the height of the header ever change? If not you can just add in a blank `div` above `.block` that has a height equal to the header. Which in this case is `height: 120px`

**EDIT**

Well you can do this with two lines of jquery

```
var headerHeight = $(".header").height();

$(".spacer").css({"height": headerHeight+"px"});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Qyu3X/1/)

Comment: Thanks, but yes the header height will change so I really need the green .block DIV to float under it not matter what the height of the header is

Comment: @Greg Since you're removing `.header` out of the document flow, there is no way how you can meet this criteria. Just set a high enough `margin-top` on `.block`.

Answer (score 0):

What if you place both divs inside of a container div and then set both header/logo divs relative to container. So, logo would be at position 0,0 and header would be at 0, 120.

Comment: This would be possible without a container and it won't allow flexible heights.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to use JavaScript to calculate the height (and even easier if you're using jQuery).  The only Non-JS option I can think of is this

1. Create your fixed header
2. Place an EXACT duplicate immediately after it, except remove `position:fixed;` and replace it with `visibility:hidden;`

### CSS

```
#header { position:fixed; height:50px; background-color:#0f0; }
#placeholder { height:50px; visibility:hidden; }
#otherDiv { height:350px; background-color:#f00; }
```

### HTML

```
<div id='header'>Text Here</div>
<div id='placeholder'>Text Here</div>
<div id='otherDiv'>Other stuff</div>
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/AUMLr/1/)

Comment: Thanks Gary - unfortunately it would not work in my case (I've added some additional info in my original post) Thanks

Comment: So, is calculating/setting it via JavaScript an option?

Comment: Yes JS is, thanks Gary. I've just approved jmore's answer. Thanks or your help!